# Configure SSL to work with Java web app on Tomcat 5.5 server

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, ssl

This is a bit of a noob question but what do I need to get SSL working in my Java web application (standard sort of Java web app using Stripes for its MVC implementation, Spring and Hibernate)?

I'm deploying my war file on Tomcat 5.5. I only want SSL to be used for certain URLS - any that are transferring the user's password - so account registration, change password, and login.

Do I just need to get an SSL cert and install it in Tomcat? How do I ensure https is used for only some URLs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do I just need to get an SSL cert and install it in Tomcat?

That will be required indeed and you'll need to configure a secured connector.

> How do I ensure https is used for only some URLs?

The [recommendation](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-A7#Protection) is to encrypt form submission (i.e. use absolute `https://` urls in the relevant form `action`) but **also** form submission pages themselves if you want to prevent man in the middle attacks.

So use "secured" absolute links everywhere you need and enforce SSL for specific content using security constraints in your `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: I don't think I really understand this part:
"The recommendation is to encrypt form submission (i.e. use absolute https:// urls in the relevant form action) but also form submission pages themselves if you want to prevent man in the middle attacks."

Maybe an example would clear things up for me?

Comment: @Annie:  Have you tried looking at the requests sent by your web-browser in a sniffing software like Fiddler or Wire-Shark?  Ever notice the difference between your requests and the requests that you might get from professional websites like facebook?

Comment: The difference is that your requests are probably not encrypted and you can actually see what you're sending and facebook's requests are encrypted and you can't see what's being sent.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `Filter` that redirects to `https://` for the URLs you want.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I just need to get an SSL cert and install it in Tomcat?

[The Tomcat manual](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html) has a pretty easy-to-follow guide on how to set ts up.

> How do I ensure https is used for only some URLs?

This piece of logic needs to be in your application. Bozho's solution would certainly work, there may be other solutions if you are using particular web frameworks or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a SSL cert. It can either be self signed or issued by an officially recognized certification authority.

Here's a good tutorial about the general setup of SSL in Tomcat and how to modify the deployment descriptor to enable SSL : http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/setting_up_ssl_and_basic

Comment: That url doesn't work. I did find this one on gmazza's blog that was related though: http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/ssl_for_web_services